# databinding to validation.haserror

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

I want to bind Validation.HasError to a boolean property on my viewmodel. I only want to know when there is a validation error so that I can disable my buttons on my VM using canexecute methods from my relay commands. I get this error though:

```
'Validation.HasError' property is read-only and cannot be set from markup.
```

I have tried different modes and they all cause this error. How do I do this? It shouldnt be this difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a Binding on a read-only dependency property. This is a known bug at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540833/onewaytosource-binding-from-a-readonly-dependency-property). You might vote for it.

The **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** shows how to listen to the Validation.HasError property and disable some buttons.

Comment: Within 15 seconds of opening that example I realized I am going re-factor my entire code base... I had no idea INotifyDataErrorInfo existed, gone are the days of using INotifyPropertyChanged to update field validation.